# Why does this program giving me unexpected behaviour

Tags: rust

I've just finished the 4th chapter of 'The Book'. To test my knowledge I was building this little project. But, for some reason I/O is not working the way I'm expecting. I was trying to figure out problem of my code, but could not. I'd really appriciate if someone can tell what the problem is.

**here's the code:**

```
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Write},
    vec,
};

fn main() {
    let mut db: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut key = String::new();
    let mut value = String::new();
    let mut operation = String::new();
    let operations = (
        String::from("put"),
        String::from("get"),
        String::from("exit"),
    );
    println!(
        "\n\tyour options are {}, {}, {}.\n",
        operations.0, operations.1, operations.2
    );
    loop {
        println!("what do you wanna do?");
        stdin()
            .read_line(&mut operation)
            .expect("colud not parse input");
        let operation = operation.trim();

        if operation == operations.0 {
            println!("enter your key");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut key)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let key = key.trim();
            println!("enter your value");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut value)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let value = value.trim();
            store(&mut db, &key, &value);
            println!("\n\tvalue `{1}` stored to key `{0}`\n", key, value);
        } else if operation == operations.1 {
            println!("enter your key");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut key)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let key = key.trim();
            println!("\n\tthe value of {} is {}\n", key, get(&mut db, &key));
        } else if operation == operations.2 {
            break;
        } else {
            println!("\n\t{} is not a valid option\n", operation);
        }
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn store(db: &mut Vec<String>, key: &str, value: &str) {
    let new_data = format!("{},{}", key, value);
    db.push(new_data);
}

fn get(db: &mut Vec<String>, key: &str) -> String {
    for data in db {
        if data.split(',').next().expect("error while parsing the key") == key {
            return data
                .split(',')
                .next()
                .expect("error while parsing the value")
                .to_string();
        }
    }
    String::from("404")
}
```

**output:**

```
        your options are put, get, exit.

what do you wanna do?
put
enter your key
name
enter your value
cob

        value `cob` stored to key `name`

what do you wanna do?
exit

        put
exit is not a valid option

what do you wanna do?     
exit

        put
exit
exit is not a valid option
```

Comment: I honestly think you should avoid stdout/stdin when learning a language.

Comment: *"unexpected behaviour"*, *"not working the way I'm expecting"*, *"if someone can tell what the problem is"* - Sure, if you tell us what your expected behaviour actually is ;)

Comment: @Stargateur would you mind adding reasoning why you have that opinion?

Comment: @Finomnis, I don't _wholeheartedly_ hold the opinion, but I do have some appreciation for it on the basis that too many teaching resources have people using stdin in circumstances where getting data off of argv would be far more conventional practice, resulting in newcomers severely underusing command-line arguments and building software that's unnecessarily difficult to automate, with relatively brittle / error-prone interfaces, as a result. Of course, I can't say that this is Stargateur's reasoning.

Comment: @Finomnis mostly what charles said, it's error prone and hard to handle, even very experimented dev have trouble with tty behavior, that why we all use lib that do this crappy thing for us and we are never happy with final result. Having to learn Rust a very hard language and at the same time fight with io difficulty and trap is quadruple trouble. That why when someone learn rust by doing thing like advance of code, it's probably better to just copy paste the input in the main or use include_str! that remove io difficulty and you can concentrate on what you actually want, learn Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the documentation of what `read_line` actually does:

> Locks this handle and reads a line of input, appending it to the specified buffer.

Meaning, it doesn't **replace** the content of `operation`, it **appends** to it.

There are two possible easy fixes:

- clear `operation` before reading
- don't keep `operation` between iterations

I'd go with #2, as I think there is no reason why `operation` is defined outside of the loop.

```rust
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Write},
    vec,
};

fn main() {
    let mut db: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut key = String::new();
    let mut value = String::new();
    let operations = (
        String::from("put"),
        String::from("get"),
        String::from("exit"),
    );
    println!(
        "\n\tyour options are {}, {}, {}.\n",
        operations.0, operations.1, operations.2
    );
    loop {
        println!("what do you wanna do?");
        let mut operation = String::new();
        stdin()
            .read_line(&mut operation)
            .expect("colud not parse input");
        let operation = operation.trim();

        if operation == operations.0 {
            println!("enter your key");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut key)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let key = key.trim();
            println!("enter your value");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut value)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let value = value.trim();
            store(&mut db, &key, &value);
            println!("\n\tvalue `{1}` stored to key `{0}`\n", key, value);
        } else if operation == operations.1 {
            println!("enter your key");
            stdin()
                .read_line(&mut key)
                .expect("could not parse the input");
            let key = key.trim();
            println!("\n\tthe value of {} is {}\n", key, get(&mut db, &key));
        } else if operation == operations.2 {
            break;
        } else {
            println!("\n\t{} is not a valid option\n", operation);
        }
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn store(db: &mut Vec<String>, key: &str, value: &str) {
    let new_data = format!("{},{}", key, value);
    db.push(new_data);
}

fn get(db: &mut Vec<String>, key: &str) -> String {
    for data in db {
        if data.split(',').next().expect("error while parsing the key") == key {
            return data
                .split(',')
                .next()
                .expect("error while parsing the value")
                .to_string();
        }
    }
    String::from("404")
}
```

Comment: FWIW clearing the string between iterations allows the loop to reuse the storage instead of allocating it every iteration